# How to push to array? push_array with names?

Tags: php

I have created an array like this.

```
$oldarray =  array('Condition' => 'New',"MinimumPrice" => "$minprice");
```

Now I need to add additional array names and values depending on if statements. How can I push_array or whatever the function would be to get the results to.

```
$finalarray = array('Condition' => 'New',"MinimumPrice" => "$minprice", 'NewLabel' => 'labelvalue');
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$x = array('Condition' => 'New',"MinimumPrice" => "$minprice");
$x['new']= 'yo';
var_dump($x);
?>
```

Simple way to add values to array in php

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    "one" => "two",
    "3" => "4",
);
```

to add more values create a loop, inside the loop will be your IF statement and add value:
 `$array[] = 'value';`

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty trivial:

```
<?php

$your_array = array('Condition' => 'New',"MinimumPrice" => "$minprice");
$your_array['NewLabel'] = 'labelvalue';

print_r($your_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array('Condition' => 'New',
               'MinimumPrice' => $minprice,
        );

$array2 = array('NewLabel' => 'labelvalue');
$finalarray = $array + $array2;
```